# Is Copy trait about bit copying only from stack?

Tags: rust

The Rust [doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) defines `Copy` marked types as

> Types whose values can be duplicated simply by copying bits

I wonder whether this definition means copying a variable value from only the stack or it includes copying heap resources too? In other words, is `Copy` just a sign for the compilier with a notice like "If you're going to create another variable of this type with the same value as one has, just copy all concerned with the first variable from the stack. That's sufficient to do."?

What if I have a type whose objects allocate a resource in a heap and I'm sure no dreadful thing would be coming up in the case of bit copying of this resource by means of `memcpy` or something. Can't I still denote the type with `Copy` (in due to Rust does only stack copying)?

Comment: Rather than stack vs heap, with `a type whose objects allocate a resource` the big concern would be how _deallocation_ happens. If a type is Copy, then you don't know how many copies there are, and if they reference allocated data, you have no way to know when to deallocate.

Comment: @loganfsmyth if it's unsafe to multiple objects which allocate resources by bitwise copying, does it mean in case of `Copy` Rust just copies variable information (nevertheless it's stored in the stack, isn't it?) and refuse to do something more?

Comment: The stack is a red herring here. You could have two heap-allocated objects with attributes `foo` and write `obj1.foo = obj2.foo`. That will perform a bitwise-copy _from heap to heap_. If the type of the `foo` field is `Copy`, it will leave `obj2` usable. If `foo` is not `Copy`, it will leave `obj2` [partially moved](https://whileydave.com/2020/11/30/understanding-partial-moves-in-rust/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I wonder whether this definition means copying a variable value from only the stack or it includes copying heap resources too?

It's the former. It refers to copying a value by performing a naive and shallow byte-by-byte copy of its data.

More precisely, `Copy` means "it is safe to bitwise-copy the value **and keep using the original value**". All Rust objects are bitwise-copied in principle, be it by assignment or passing to functions, etc. The difference when the object is not `Copy` is that the object is said to be *moved*, and the compiler doesn't allow you to access the object that was the source of the copy. (The compiler will also not drop the original object if it implements `Drop` because it will be dropped by the new owner.)

> In other words, is Copy just a sign for the compilier with a notice like "If you're going to create another variable of this type with the same value as one has, just copy all concerned with the first variable from the stack. That's sufficient to do."?

Yes.

> What if I have a type whose objects allocate a resource in a heap and I'm sure no dreadful thing would be coming up in the case of bit copying of this resource by means of memcpy or something. Can't I still denote the type with Copy (in due to Rust does only stack copying)?

There is no way (and will likely never be a way) to denote such a type as `Copy`. If you want to allow copying such objects, you have to make them `Clone` and require the user to type `.clone()` explicitly. That's one of the things meant by claims that Rust "makes allocations explicit".

Note that none of this requires either the source or the destination of the copy to be allocated on the stack. They could as well be [sub-fields of heap-allocated objects](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8fd1fbf437e04d2cfbaa644088d87394), and the same principles would apply equally. The "stack" is irrelevant: what matters is whether the byte-by-byte value transfer is considered a "copy" or "move", and that will depend on whether the type is `Copy`.